# in WordPress site only any three post are access then redirect to register page

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Here I want help for when user comes to my site and click on any of their WordPress default 8 or 10 post, then that IP is restricted (Means force to redirect another page when he / she access my Wordpress default post) for 30 days... My site built in WordPress....

Comment: Are you looking for a plugin or code?

Comment: Thanks for reply anything Plugin or code...

Comment: You have to put some efforts , this community is help those who did something and stuck at anywhere. I don't find any efforts from your side. You are directly asking for the code only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a plugin for this where you have to add logic for each user to store their activity for post with IP address and set the timestamp for the 30 days for that user. You also have to add condition while any user come to your post at that time you can compare the timestamp and IP with current timestamp and based on that you have to redirect user to registration page.

You also have to set flag for the user and IP so you can allow them to access your post if they are registered user.

Comment: First time user can access 8 or 9 posts without register... After visiting 8 or 9 then that IP visit any WordPress post, then redirect to register page...

Answer (score 0):

There are two solution for that One is to create a plugin and second is to add it to your theme.

If you want to implement without plugin then you have to apply the logic into your function.php file and create a table which will add trace details of your user in db. At that you can check for user criteria to making call to db and accessing post hooks provided by Wordpress.